# Java Eclipse Export keeping folderstructure

Tags: java, eclipse, export, filestructure

I'm getting my java project to a finish and I'm about to export it to an easy useable program on the desktop.
In my program I'm using .txt files to keep all my data, so I've made a folder for my databases and my images.
The problem comes when I'm exporting the project to the desktop and it looks like everything mashes up and becomes one big pile of files instead of a folder structure I made it like in eclipse.

[From eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH4Ow.png)

What is the right way to export the project, and how does I keep my filestructure?
Exporting to JAR file at the moment.

EDIT:
I'm also getting this error when I try to follow exampels from the internet.

```
'Utforsking/src/org/eclipse/wb/swing/FocusTraversalOnArray.java'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose export->General->File System.

Then choose "Create directory structure for files" and that should work. I am using Luna.

If you hit problems, let me know.

Comment: Yes, I get the whole filestructure out, but all my javafiles does not run..
Kind of new to eclipse, so having some startuptrouble with this.

What I want is to have a folder with my runnable file, and the subfolders that i can edit as i want (the .txt documents).

Comment: Ok, this is a different problem. You have several options, export a jar file with everything in it, export a jar file for the binary and folders for your files or export class files into a directory and your text files in another. Which do you prefer? Once you determine what you want, you can automate with ant or maven.